# Basic C# text adventure is broken

Tags: c#

When I press a key it gives me all the text related to that key instead of just the first `WriteLine`.

For example when I press `Q` even on the first screen, it says

```
"the door opens and you are blinded by the sun"
"you walk to the town and are taken back to your cell"
```

Instead of just bringing me to the next decision making point.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Int

        //String

        Console.WriteLine("you find yourself in a dark room");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("In front of you is a door");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'W' to go through");
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You enter a room with two doors on either side");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Q' to go left or 'E' to go right");
        {
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.E)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You enter the room to the right and are eaten by a grue");
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The door opens and you are blinded by the sun");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("You walk down the road and come to a fork in it");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Q' to go left, 'E' to go right, or 'W' to pick up the fork!");
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You walk to a town and are taken back to your cell by the guards");

            }
        }
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.E)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You escape into the mountains! you win! ");

        }
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you pick up the fork unravelling space and time. You monster.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Well you're only calling `ReadKey` once... and although you're testing for `W` being pressed, you're not taking any other action if that first key *isn't* `W` - you're just not displaying the "room with two doors"... what do you want to happen there? Do you want to loop round until the user *does* press `W`? It doesn't help that your code isn't well formatted, and you have a nested block for no obvious reason (after the first "press Q to go left etc")

Comment: _Great wall of code hits you for 10 damage!_

Comment: The indentation in this code is magical :-) 
Don't know if its because you did not try to make it cleaner

Answer (score 4):

You need one `key = Console.ReadKey(true);` right before **every** decision making point. e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press 'Q' to go left or 'E' to go right");
key = Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kelvin Lai's answer is of course correct, the single key press you've received is used for every test of `key.Key` throughout your code.  You never get the user to enter anything else.

Which you could find out fairly simply by stepping through your code with the built-in debugger in your IDE.

Anyway, back to the problems…

You have a few cases where you have put expression blocks that serve no purpose, and in fact simply conceal what is happening.  When you ask a question of the user inside one expression and the answer (that you never actually get - refer to main problem) is processed in an outer block, that's confusing as all hell.

Your formatting is all over the place.  How do you expect to be able to understand your code when you appear to have gone out of your way to complicate it?

Style aside, your program is a non-recursive decision tree where no connections exist between the branches.  What if you want to add in a loop back to a previous room… boom, you have to copy the entire tree from that point down.

Here are a few things that you can do to fix this up.

First, keyboard interaction.  Write a method that you can call with a list of valid keys and have loop around waiting for one of those keys to come up.  When you have a decision point to present to the user, call that method with the list of valid keys.  Don't forget to include some way to break out and exit the program, although the good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> exit will work unless you disable it.

Next, give some thought to laying each of the rooms out as an object.  Each will need some basic information:

- An identity - a number generally, a name if you prefer
- A description of the room/situation
- A list of acceptable keys, their descriptions and where they take you

With that you can write an outer loop that takes the current room, displays the description, presents the options and waits for the user to enter something, then selects the appropriate next room.  Once you have that it's just a matter of setting up whatever list of rooms you want it to work on.

And of course it then allows you to have room loops, branches, etc. because instead of a straight tree you now have a *map.*

And of course if you're using a data structure instead of code then changing the general flow becomes *much* simpler.  Adding a room is just a matter of tacking on some extra information to the room list and connecting it via the option lists for another room.